# Expanding BW using feedback

Tags: feedback

I have built the following two stage amplifier as shown below. In open loop I get 63 dB gain and BW about 3 kHz. When I tried to add a feedback resistor to lower the gain and increase the bandwidth as shown in the formula below I get no change at all. Two stage amplifier with feedback is shown in the end.

Where did I go wrong in implementing the feedback effect of feedback resistor to lower the gain and increase the bandwidth?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: R7 isn't a feedback resistor at all.  It can't impact the value of Vin, or, ideally, Vout.  It's just a resistor between 2 low/zero impedance points.

Comment: Two inverting amplifiers require feeding back output to "+" input of the first stage.

Answer (score 0):

Look at just one stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDuMST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ ***sees*** a divider formed between itself and \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$. That is what gets summed into the wire there at the (-) input. \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$ ***sees*** a divider formed between itself and \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$. That is also what gets summed into the wire at the (-) input. This is then compared with ground, as expected, and the difference multiplied by the open loop gain of the opamp, \$A\$, to get the final \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$ result.

Using the second stage with lower-numbered parts, start with \$Z_{_\text{IN}}=R_1\$ and \$Z_{_\text{F}}=R_2\mid\mid Z_{_{\text{C}_1}}\$:

```
def par(a,b): return a*b/(a+b)
Zin = r1
Zf = par(r2,1/s/c1)
n1,d1 = fraction(solve(Eq((0-(vin*Zf/(Zf+Zin)+vout*Zin/(Zf+Zin)))*A,vout),vout)[0])
simplify(n1/A) / expand(simplify(d1/A))
-r2*vin/(c1*r1*r2*s + r1 + c1*r1*r2*s/A + r1/A + r2/A)
```

And as \$A\to\infty\$ then find \$V_{_\text{OUT}}=-V_{_\text{IN}}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+R_2\,C_1\,s}\$.

If instead we solve the KCL (\$V_1\$ being the (-) input node) then:

```
solve(Eq(v1/r1+v1/r2+v1*s*c1,vin/r1+vout/r2+vout*s*c1),vout)[0].subs(v1,0)
-r2*vin/(r1*(c1*r2*s + 1))
```

Which is the exact same result. So nothing new. But it does show that the feedback diagram above matches your schematic for one stage.

If you are to bring back negative feedback to the pair of stages, note first that your final output is in-phase with the input. (And with both stages, I'd expect about \$65\:\text{dB}\$ gain at the output, discounting opamp details.)

Suppose you wanted to reduce the gain to \$40\:\text{dB}\$ and only make the simplest change (and ignore whatever it does to the \$Q\$ of the circuit.) Then:

```
def gain(a): return 10**(a/20).n()
solve(Eq(732.82/(732.82+x),solve(Eq(gain(65)/(1+gain(65)*x),gain(40)),x)[0]),x)[0]
76915.6758028831
```

So, this suggests a feedback resistor of about \$76.9\:\text{k}\Omega\$ connected back to the first stage's (+) input. (Leave the existing grounded resistor in place.) This approach was already suggested in comments. Why don't you try this and see?

Comment: Hello crutschow, i have implemented your advice and got incread of BW from 3K to 30K as shown in the links bellow.
Is there some alternative OPAMP i can use to increase much more my BW?(to 5MHz)
Thanks.

https://ibb.co/NKVPg76
https://ibb.co/s6gWYB9

Comment: @lub2354 Everything would need to change. Not just the opamps. Much more information would be needed, besides. Perhaps ask another question? And who exactly is 'crut'?

Comment: Hello periblepsis,could you please give me some material on a better high bandwidth implementation?
Thanks.

Comment: @lub2354 High bandwidth, high gain amplifiers aren't in my experience. I'd have to defer to others. This gets into an area where many details matter a great deal. You may need to be very specific about your goals and what you are hoping to achieve. But it would still be outside my experience.